# Custom nuget.config globalPackagesFolder via .NET 5 CLI?

Tags: nuget, config, .net-5

Recently I have been working up some training lessons for .NET 5 using VSCode for my company, and have previously used a nuget.config (in the same folder as my solution file) as such:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <configuration>
  <config>
    <add key="globalPackagesFolder" value="..\lib\nuget" />
  </config>
  <solution>
    <add key="disableSourceControlIntegration" value="true" />
  </solution>
</configuration>
```

Which allows all of the restored packages for that solution to stay within the solution folder structure. And this works great for these transient training projects, however, while I can create a nuget.config via the **dotnet** CLI using:

```
dotnet new nugetconfig --output ../src/
```

The CLI does not seem to provide a way to add **config** or **solution** items to the file. It does provide a way for me to add **packageSources** items, but I'm not really interested in where my packages are coming from, but rather where they are going to.

Is this just something we need to continue to do manually, or is there something I'm missing. Can this be done through the CLI in some way (if so I haven't figured it out yet)? I want to use as much of the CLI as possible so the end trainees don't have to perform too many manual steps like "please download and copy this file to this location...", to get the desired functionality.

Please note I specifically reference this **globalPackagesFolder** as part of the training to show new hires how nuget operates. And they can clear out the folder without impacting the larger development environment as they are learning. In later lessons we show how sometimes files from this folder need to be manually copied to the project folders (jQuery, etc.) using **ItemGroups** and **Targets** in the project file like this:

```
  <ItemGroup>  
    <jQuery Include="../../../lib/nuget/jquery/3.3.1/Content/Scripts/jquery-3.3.1.js;../../../lib/nuget/jquery/3.3.1/Content/Scripts/jquery-3.3.1.min.js;../../../lib/nuget/jquery/3.3.1/Content/Scripts/jquery-3.3.1.min.map;../../../lib/nuget/jquery/3.3.1/Content/Scripts/jquery-3.3.1-vsdoc.js;"/>  
  </ItemGroup>  

  <Target Name="ClientSideContent" AfterTargets="AfterBuild">
    <Copy SourceFiles="@(jQuery)" DestinationFolder="./root/Scripts" />
  </Target>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, so it looks like, at present, you can not do this through the dotnet CLI (maybe in the future), but you can currently do it through the nuget CLI, so after using the dotnet CLI to create the config, running:

```
nuget config -Set globalPackagesFolder=..\lib\nuget -configfile ../src/nuget.config
```

will add:

```
<config>
  <add key="globalPackagesFolder" value="..\lib\nuget" />
</config>
```

to the nuget.config file, of course this requires that the nuget CLI is already installed and included in your PATH.